# How to draw a framed shape with FOR-loops

Tags: java, for-loop

This is my code to draw a filled square

```
public void draw() 
{   
    System.out.println("filled square with a length of : " + this.getlength() );

    for ( int i=0 ; i < this.getlength() ; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for ( int j=0 ; j < this.getlength() ; j ++)
        {   
            System.out.print("$"); 
        } 
    }
    System.out.println("\n"); 
}
```

But I want to know how that it will still work if I want a framed shape.
Do I need more than two FOR-loops?
Any example will help me  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just analyze your code:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i < this.getlength() ; i++) {
    for ( int j=0 ; j < this.getlength() ; j ++) {
        System.out.print("$");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The inner code makes a full line of `$` then use it one time:

```
for ( int j=0 ; j < this.getlength() ; j ++) {
    System.out.print("$");
System.out.println();
```

Then you just need to have `getLength()-2` "empty" lines (an empty line starts with one $ then n-2 spaces and terminates with a single $):

```
for ( int i=1 ; i < this.getlength()-1 ; i++) {
    System.out.print('$');
    for ( int j=1 ; j < this.getlength()-1 ; j ++) {
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
   System.out.println('$');
}
```

And then a full line at the end:

```
for ( int j=0 ; j < this.getlength() ; j ++) {
    System.out.print("$");
}
System.out.println();
```

Another way could be:

```
for ( int i=0 ; i < this.getlength() ; i++) {
    for ( int j=0 ; j < this.getlength() ; j ++) {
        if (i==0 || j==0 || i==this.getLength()-1 || j==this.getLength()-1)
            System.out.print("$");
        else
            System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

where the idea is: if the coordinates correspond to the frame then print a $, and if coordinates correspond to the inner space then print a space.

Comment: thank you very much it really help me to understand how it works , because i tried to do it with two for loops but it seems to be Impossible .

Comment: Don't you think my second solution is "with only two for loops"?

Comment: yep i know it with two for loops and i prefer  to do the second one  , but i mean when i tried at the first time it seems to be impossible with me :)